# Воспроизведение видео из буфера (webm-vp8/vp9) в Control'е

Tags: c#, online-video

Уже 2ю неделю ищу библиотеку для воспроизведения онлайн-видео (с аудиодорожкой) на форме (winform/wpf).
Я могу получить прямую ссылку на видео (или склеить из ts-фрагментов) и скачать его в byte[] или MemoryStream (или альтернативное представление в памяти), но в случае с Webm - не могу найти (не проприетарную) библиотеку, которая предоставила бы Control для размещения на форме (Winforms/Wpf), которой бы можно было скормить byte[] или Stream, и проигрывать на этом контроле видео Webm (vp8/vp9) со звуком.
Если таких библиотек для C# существует в природе несколько - управление (переход к отметке времени), воспроизведение не до конца загруженного видео, и возможность воспроизведения mp4 (h264/h265) было бы хорошим плюсом.
PS на диск сбрасывать временно, чтобы запускать дочерний процесс, пробрасывая его окно в Control - не вариант.

Кто сталкивался и нашёл решение, или хотя-бы знает подобную библиотеку - подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Примерно 2 года назад решал данную проблему через CefSharp. То есть полноценный браузер встроенный в форму, делал страничку с встроенным веб-плеером и грузил туда видео. Решение, конечно, корявенькое, зато очень эффективное, и позволяет выбирать из огромного количества плееров.

Comment: @SoulOFTrue браузер - не вариант, т.к. может потребоваться сохранить видео, не качать же повторно, к тому-же занимает много озу.

Comment: Потыкал libvlc, вроде получается, но ещё не до конца понятно, смущает пока одно, папка Debug\bin\libvlc\ - весит 360мб, а это очень много, в сравнении ffmpeg с ним копейки, но как его так-же задействовать...